# Dúvida no update do banco de dados através de um modal

Tags: javascript, ajax, banco-de-dados

Tenho um formulário através de um modal, onde o mesmo realiza atualizações no banco de dados MySQL. No entanto, existe momentos que ao clicar em "Encaminhar" a ação não é executada, e em outros momentos a ação funciona normalmente, sem problema nenhum. Então queria saber se tem alguma coisa de errado no meu JavaScript, já que tem horas que ele funciona tranquilo e outras não.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#salvar').click(function () {
        var destino = "<?php echo base_url('protocolo/updatetramitacao') ?>";
        var dados = {
            'area': $("#area").val(),
            'status': $('#status').val(),
            'idhistorico': $('#hidden').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: destino,
            data: dados,
            success: function (response) {
                alert('Protocolo encaminhado com sucesso!');
                location.reload();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Função update:

```
 public function updatetramitacao(){
    $dados['area_id'] = $this->input->post('area');
    $dados['situacao_id'] = $this->input->post('status');
    $this->protocolo->atualizarhistorico($dados, array('protocolo_id' => $this->input->post('idhistorico')));

    $resultdados = $this->db->query('SELECT datap FROM historico WHERE protocolo_id ='.$this->input->post('idhistorico'));
    $resulthistorico = $resultdados->row();

     $this->db->query('UPDATE historico set datat = NOW() WHERE protocolo_id = '. $this->input->post('idhistorico')
        . ' AND datat is null');
    $dados10['protocolo_id'] = $this->input->post('idhistorico');
    $dados10['area_id'] = $this->input->post('area');
    $dados10['situacao_id'] = $this->input->post('status');
    $dados10['datap'] = $resulthistorico->datap;
    $this->protocolo->do_insert_historicos($dados10);

    $response = array("success" => true);
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Formulário:

```
<?php
 $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
 if ($id > 0) {
 $querys = $this->protocolo->get_protocol_hist($id)->row();
 ?>
  <form action="" id="user2">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Encaminhar protocolo</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-6 columns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                        <label for="pt">Protocolo</label>
                        <input type="text" name="protocolo" id="protocolo" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $querys->id ?>">  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                        <label for="area">Área</label>
                        <select name="area" id="area">
                            <?php
                            $array = array();
                            $query = $this->area->get_all_areas()->result();
                            foreach ($query as $area) {
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $area->id ?>"><?php echo $area->area ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="small-6 columns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                        <label for="numero">Número do documento</label>
                        <input type="text" name="documento" id="documento" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $querys->numerodocumento ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                        <label for="status">Status</label>
                        <select name="status" id="status">
                            <?php
                            $array = array();
                            $query = $this->situacao->get_all_situacao()->result();
                            foreach ($query as $linha) {
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $linha->id ?>"><?php echo $linha->situacao ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="button" value="Encaminhar" id="salvar" class="button small font encaminhar radius">
            </div>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215</a> 
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="hidden" name="idhistorico" value="<?php echo $querys->id; ?>">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Ele apresenta algum erro no seu console nas vezes em que não é executado?

Comment: POST 
http://localhost/sistemaProtocolo/protocolo/updatetramitacao [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 47 ms Deu esse erro.

Comment: Como você perguntou sobre seu javascript, ao meu ver não está com problemas. Tem algum bug na sua função de update, você possuí alguma IDE para "debugar" passo a passo o que ocorre nela e ver aonde exatamente acontece o erro?

Comment: Estou usando o Netbeans!!

Comment: Você tem o XDebug ativado e funcionando? Coloque um breakpoint no começo da função logo nesta linha: `$dados['area_id'] = $this->input->post('area');` e vai dando f8 até acontecer o bug e veja pela janela do debug qual foi o erro que aconteceu... ou tenta colocar um `try catch(\Exception $e) {}` genérico para pegar o erro. Olhando assim não sei dizer qual pode ser o erro... mas tem algumas coisas ali que você deve tomar cuidado, como a concatenação de string para formar o SQL.

Comment: Vou verificar aqui, qualquer coisa comento, vlw pela ajuda ;)

Comment: Foi resolvido, era um detalhe! Vlw ;)